# Converting MySQL datetime to RSS pubDate using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, rss

i was wondering how would I convert datetime using PHP to work with RSS feeds pubDate?

Why is my browser 3 hours off when displaying the time? Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 11):

Assuming `$row` is the resultant row of `mysql_fetch_assoc()` of your result, and your date column is called `date`:

```
<pubDate><?php echo gmdate(DATE_RSS, strtotime($row['date'])); ?></pubDate>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<pubDate><? echo date("r", strtotime($data["added_on"])); ?></pubDate>
```

Courtesy of the [first google result](http://www.phpjabbers.com/ask93-mysql-date-to-rss-pubdate.html) on 'mysql rss pubdate'

Edit: The off-time is probably due to timezone issues; it's not your browser, probably, it's the time being generated by PHP. Have you configured your PHP instance properly?

Edit: Sorry for the confusion guys, forgot to added the "Edit:" remark. No need to bash on the asker!

Comment: Why is my browser 3 hours off when displaying the time?

Comment: @meta Did you even read the answer before commenting? He told you: it's the time being generated by PHP, so check your timezone configuration in PHP.

Comment: @Martin: did you even read and compare the timestamps of OP's comment and kander's edit?

Comment: Fair enough, egg truly worn on face!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class as follows:

```
$objDate = new DateTime($itemDate);
$rssDate = $objDate->format(DateTime::RSS);
```

Where $row['date'] is the date from your row in MySQL.  $rssDate with contain the properly formatted RSS Date.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT added_on FROM 'table');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<pubDate><? echo date("r", strtotime($data["added_on"]));} ?></pubDate>
```

As [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329977/converting-mysql-datetime-to-rss-pubdate-using-php/3329996#3329996) used the gmdate you WILL get the  time in GMT, so you could calculate where you are easier.
 That said PHP is server side thus your browser might be +- 3 hours because the server is in a +-3 time zone from your browser.
If you are experiencing that problem locally check for weird [locales](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime()` to convert it into Unix timestamp then convert it into desired format using `date()`